# Can a formal algorithm contain steps which do not do anything?

Tags: algorithm

I was going through formal definitions of algorithms. It appears from the definitions that an algorithm can contain steps which do no computation.

For example, the below code is from Wikipedia. I added one statement(between asterisks). My question is, according to the formal definition of algorithm, am I allowed to write such statements? Can it be refuted or accepted based on the Turing Complete approach? Thanks in advance.

```
Algorithm LargestNumber
  Input: A list of numbers L.
  Output: The largest number in the list L.
  if L.size = 0 return null
  largest ← L[0]
  ***wait (10)***   wait for 10 seconds
  for each item in L, do
    if item > largest, then
      largest ← item
  return largest
```

Comment: There is no sinlgle formal definition of an algorithm. It's unlikely that an algorithm description on wikipedia would follow a formal definition. There's no reason why a formal definition could not contain a "wait" instruction and a concept of time. A turing machine does not have such a thing, but then this algorithm is not a turing machine program.

Comment: The `wait (10)` instruction seems like not doing anything from a high level. But if you would write this code in assembly or any lower level language, you would find that it is doing many operations (like incrementing the time counter for example). And because turing machines are low-level, writing this code in a turing machine will have lot of instructions that are all doing something.

Comment: This is a question about the definition of the phrase "formal algorithm", which doesn't have a universally accepted definition.  In practical terms, I would say that you can write this in the description of an algorithm, but it's unlikely that your algorithm will be correct.  If you're actually trying to write an algorithm that needs such a thing, you should ask about that specifically.

Comment: Okay. So it seems there is no universally accepted 'formal definition' of algorithm. I think I have my doubts cleared. Thanks